# Extract the DOM of an element and Print it excel worksheet or as text file

Tags: c#

I have implemented an app with a checkedlistbox which generates links, buttons etc... of provided website with a button click. How can I get the DOM Model of a selected element when I check the relevant checkbox and press a button?

---

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(textBox1.Text);
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;

    }

    public void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)

    {

        HtmlDocument source = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document;
        extractLink(source);

    }

    public void extractLink(HtmlDocument source)

    {
        List<string> urlList = new List<string>();
        HtmlElementCollection anchorList = source.GetElementsByTagName("a");

        foreach (var item in anchorList)

        {

            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(((HtmlElement)item).GetAttribute("href"));
            urlList.Add(((HtmlElement)item).GetAttribute("href"));

        }

    }
```

Comment: Above is the code to generate links. So how can I generate the specific DOM for a selected link?

Comment: Guys is there any solution for this?

Comment: I need to get attributes for the above extracted element from the check box. (This is the method to get all the links to checklist box.) I need to get the attributes for the checked link